Renewing UK passport also holding an Irish passport
I am a British Citizen from birth but hold an Irish passport. My British passport has expired and I am trying to renew it. The passport office is asking that I send them my foreign passport. I don't remember informing them that I hold another passport. I have not had to do this before and don't really want to send it, in case they lose it or don't return it in time for when I next travel.

Did I tell them or have they worked it out because I tend to use the Irish one?
Since when was it a requirement to send my Irish one?  I've had a UK passport for 35 years and the Irish one for more than 20


"I don't remember informing them that I hold another passport": did you inform them that you are an Irish citizen?  If so, they may simply be assuming that you hold an Irish passport.  "...or have they worked it out because I tend to use the Irish one?": Have you presented your Irish passport to UK immigration officers (or an automated passport control kiosk) upon entering the UK?

I can't remember if it was a question on the renewal form.  I mainly use my Irish passport to travel so would have presented it.  But I have done this for many years and renewed 2/3 times without having to send my other passport to them.  Just wondering if and why it is necessary?

I believe there's been a change in the administrative requirements but don't know the details.  I imagine someone who does will post soon.

The requirement is indeed fairly recent-last 5-10 years I believe. The policy is that the names on your passports must align, so they require dual nationals to send in their other passport(s) to facilitate this.
https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/names-aligning-names-on-foreign-documents/names-aligning-names-on-foreign-documents-accessible
As for how they know, you are supposed to tell them on the passport form, but presumably they may have found out through some other method.

Ok, seems you can send a colour photocopy, although they want all 36 pages v0v

@CaptainZep Please write that as an answer. It's fine to answer your own question.

I am in the same situation and I was also reluctant.  However, I could not see any way to avoid it and I accepted it.  I was not quite unable to travel while both passports were away as I also have an Irish passport card.  So, I could still travel to EU countries and a few others.  In general, you cannot enter the UK with an EU ID card any longer but you may still use an Irish one.  This is according to a government website; I have not yet tried to enter the UK with only my Irish passport card.
Visiting the UK as an EU, EEA or Swiss citizen
When my son renewed his UK passport, he was asked for a scan of his non-UK passport but he did not have to send it in.
